# Azure bot - show chat notifications in notification bar in cross platform moobile app (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, botframework

i wanted to show azure's chat bots responses as notifications in the notification bar like PUSH notifications.

I've came across that i need to use xamarin webview to integrate bot in Android app. So, can webview capable of showing chat responses as push notifications ?

Note:-
I'm using Bot Framework SDK V4
and .Net Core
Xamarin for cross platform development

Answer (score 0):

The WebChat control (webview in your questions) is used as a UX display control within your app. Messages from your bot to your app goes through a dedicated channel that has nothing to do with a mobile Push Notification. So in short, the answer to your question is *no*, this functionality is currently not supported by the client Webview control (WebChat).

With that said, you can create a custom [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) component for your bot that can send a Push Notification message using [Azure Notification Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview). Or you can create c[ustom functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification) (sample showing a standard web app) in your bot that sends a push notification. Or your bot can drop a message to a queue and have an [Azure Function pick the queue message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs) and send the push notification. Note the last option is an implementation detail.